# based on a value in column A, shift the values in columns C and D to the right in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can i achieve the desired result based on the following dataset ?

```
        A     B      C      D      E       
1    apple    5      2     20    NaN
2    orange   2      6     30    NaN
3    apple    6      1     40    NaN
4    apple    10     3     50    NaN
5    banana   8      9     60    NaN
```

Desired Result :

```
        A     B      C      D      E       
1    apple    5    NaN      2     20
2    orange   2      6     30    NaN
3    apple    6    NaN      1     40    
4    apple    10   NaN      3     50    
5    banana   8      9     60    NaN
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to search for row with apple in column A and then shift the values found under column C and D for that specific row to the right - as shown in desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) on the rows of interest, here we need to select only the rows where 'A' is 'apple' and then `roll` these by a single column row-wise and assign back:

```
In [14]:    
df.loc[df['A']=='apple', 'C':] = np.roll(df.loc[df['A']=='apple', 'C':], 1,axis=1)
df

Out[14]:
        A   B    C   D     E
1   apple   5  NaN   2  20.0
2  orange   2  6.0  30   NaN
3   apple   6  NaN   1  40.0
4   apple  10  NaN   3  50.0
5  banana   8  9.0  60   NaN
```

Note that because you introduce `NaN` values the `dtype` changes to `float` to allow this

Comment: I suppose from the description of the question, OP wants to perform a shift rather than a roll operation here. In your case, the values present under column E would get swapped to column C if E takes on finite values.

Comment: i tested it. After the roll, the values in column C becomes NaN. Probably because E has NaN ?

Comment: @Sun yes this is correct, if you want a different behaviour then you need to define your problem more clearly

Comment: for now this i am seeing the behavior i expected. Thanks.